# Inject script using fiddler, except for iframe requests

Tags: http, fiddler

I'm using Fiddler to inject a javascript library like so:

```
if( oSession.HostnameIs("www.mysite.com") ) 
{
  oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('</head>','<script src="//myLibrary.js"></script></head>');
}
```

This works by prepending my script to the closing `</head>`.

I've noticed that this will also inject it in any iframes on the page, but would like to prevent this.

**question**: Is there a way to do this while excluding iframes within Fiddler's customRules.js file?

Note, I will not know what site will be loaded in these iframes, so a generic solution is needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're asking: "*Can a proxy know whether or not a given request is for a top-level frame or for an iframe?*"

The answer is basically "no." If you set the `X-Download-Initiator` option in IE (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/02/10/fiddler-is-better-with-internet-explorer-9.aspx) you can get *some* awareness, but this only works in IE and you shouldn't set this option except on your own computer.